# How to parse data from a text file?

Tags: php, parsing, text

My file is in the following format how will i take the data corresponding to each column? I am exploding using space as delimitter, but the problem is with the name field.

```
Id.          Name.            Rank
1.           jack and          5
              jill
2.           rose mary        2
```

Now only jill is the issue

```
$text = file_get_contents("Sample.txt");
$header=false;
$headerarr=array('Id','Name','Rank');
$values = explode("\n",$text);
$finalarr=array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
  
    if(str_contains($value,"Name")){
      $header=true;
      continue;
    }

    if($header){

      $value = str_replace("      ",",,",$value);
      $value = preg_replace("/,{2,}/", "*", $value);
      $newvalue = explode("*",$value);
      if(count($headerarr)==count($newvalue))
        $finalarr[] = array_combine($headerarr, $newvalue);

    }
}
print_r($finalarr);
```

Comment: You will need to standardize your accepted formats, or create/find parsers for each format.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to parse the name field

Comment: "jack and jill" is really on two separate lines?? Who made up this crazy format? If you can fix the format, your life will be a lot easier. As it stands, even from these basic examples, this is going to be quite tricky to get right.

Comment: yea some names are really comming in two line . atleast for 'rose mary' types of data if some one could help..

Comment: Please show your code so far, then we can see more easily where you are getting stuck, and suggest a solution which fits. We're happy to help you here, but we don't like having to repeat any work you've already done, so please edit the question to show us your current code.